Single pole switch with two hot wires?
I discovered a switch in a house we purchased that seems to have a red (test hot) and a black (test hot) hooked up to a wall switch. I cannot find what the switch controls. All the lights work and all the outlets work, even with the switch disconnected.
I assumed the switch was to control an outlet since there is no ceiling light in that room but the outlets are not affected.
Red, white, black, ground from left romex & two romex on right with black, white, ground.
All white wires tied together (no pig tail), all black wires tied together (pig tail to switch and test live), red wire (also test live) to switch.

Did you test both outlets on each duplex outlet?  Many times they are split.

...or used to be split at one time until someone replaced the outlet and kept the tabs between the terminals intact.

If you measure voltage between both sides that test as live, do you get any voltage measurement?

I did test each outlet top and bottom and all are hot even with the wire removed from the switch .  I will have to test the true voltage coming from each line .  You can tell the red and black (pig tails) wire is original to home because you see the wires all are sprayed from the original wall painting when home was built in 2004.  I was hoping to avoid crawling through the attic and tracing the wires.

As others have already noted in comments, split duplex receptacles are a thing. Here is one possible scenario:
In the Switch box

Black/White from panel to switch box

Black/White from switch box to next receptacle or switch or whatever

Black/Red/White from switch box to split receptacle

All whites are neutral and connected together

All blacks are hot and connected together and to one screw on the switch

Red wire connected to the switch


In the split receptacle box

White to the neutral side (either screw)
Red to top of the hot side
Black to bottom of the hot side
Tab removed on the hot side, left in place on the neutral side

With this configuration, the switch controls the top receptacle and the bottom receptacle is always on.
Receptacle Replacement
Due to necessity (e.g., burnt up receptacle) or other reasons (e.g., replace black with white or vice versa) the duplex receptacle is replaced with a new duplex receptacle. The wires are placed in the exact same locations. However, the tab is not removed from the hot side.
The result will be:

Both top and bottom are always on
Both black and red wires on the switch are hot, whether the switch is on or off

which happens to match OP's description.
Check all receptacles in the room for red wires. If exactly one has a red wire then that's the one that needs fixing. If more than one has a red wire then it gets more complicated. Assuming it is just one, remove the tab on the hot (black and red wires) side and the receptacle with the red wire can be turned on/off with the switch.
While personally I prefer hardwired ceiling fixtures, some people prefer receptacles for cord/plug connected lamps. However, you can't put a dimmer switch on a receptacle (with some very limited exceptions) because that would be a very bad thing if you happened to plug in something else instead of a lamp.
I have been in homes where there is a permanent piece of tape over a wall switch because the computer (or other stuff that shouldn't be turned off by a wall switch) is plugged into a switched receptacle. Sad, but true.

As an alternative remedy, if you prefer to have the receptacle non-switched, once you have identified the receptacle with both red and black wires (and an intact tab), disconnect and cap off the red wire at both ends and remove the switch.
